# Distribution for number of draws until we get a given number

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and independently draw until I get $0$: let $X$ denote a number of draws. How to find a distribution of such a random variable? At first I thought that if for example $X = 3$ in two first draws I can get whatever number I want except for $0$ and then only $0$, but is that correct?

Comment: Please go into more detail about what you have tried by editing your post. Without sufficient details and an honest attempt this question will likely be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ denote the pmf of $X$ such that $p(k)$ is the probability that that $0$ is obtained for the first time at the $k$:th draw.

We see that $p(1)=1/10$ since, in order to get $0$ after the first draw, we must pick $0$ out of $10$ equally likely numbers.

We see that $p(2)=9/10 \cdot 1/10 = 9/100$, since in the first draw we must pick any of the 9 numbers out of 10 apart from 0, and in the second draw we must pick 0 out of 10 numbers.

In a similar spirit, we see that $$p(k) = (9/10)^{k-1}\cdot 1/10, \ \mathrm{for} \ k \geq 1.$$
Indeed, in the first $k-1$ draws we must pick, with probability $9/10$, any of the 9 numbers out of 10 apart from 0, and in the last draw, we must pick 0 out of 10 numbers.

As a sanity check, let us note that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(k) = (9/10)^{k-1}\cdot 1/10  = \frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{1-9/10} = 1,$$
as it should be.

What you have is an example of a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Comment: Please review *carefully* the current policy of [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1), which now applies to not only askers, but also the answerers that answer very low quality questions.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Thank you for drawing my attention to this! Should I leave my answer or delete it?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and understand this has nothing to do with the quality of your solution. I will leave it to you to decide to delete or not. The question is likely to get closed anyways due to it not meeting MSE quality standards. Please do adhere to this in the future as answering low quality questions makes the problem worse. We are trying to prevent MSE from becoming a place where people just ask for solutions to their HW problems. This is neither useful or interesting. If you see others posting solutions to low quality questions, I would encourage you to post the message above.